# is there a way to make a value non-negative in dataframe

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, cryptocurrency

I'm new to coding and I'm using python pandas to practice making an algo-trading bot. This is my code.

```
for date in BTCtest.index:
  if BTCtest.loc[date,'Shares'] == 0:
    BTCtest.loc[date,'Shares'] = max(0,-5)
  if BTCtest.loc[date, 'MA10'] > BTCtest.loc[date, 'MA50']:
    BTCtest.loc[date, 'Shares'] = 1
  elif BTCtest.loc[date, 'MA10'] < BTCtest.loc[date, 'MA50']:
    BTCtest.loc[date, 'Shares'] = -1

BTCtest['Position'] = BTCtest['Shares'].cumsum()
BTCtest['Close1'] = BTCtest['Close'].shift(-1)
BTCtest['Profit'] = [BTCtest.loc[date, 'Close1'] - BTCtest.loc[date, 'Close'] if BTCtest.loc[date, 'Shares']==1 else 0 for date in BTCtest.index]
BTCtest['Profit'].plot()
print (BTCtest)

plt.axhline(y=0, color='red')
```

This is my code and I'm trying to not add shares when the position is 0.
I tried

```
if BTCtest.loc[date,'Shares'] == 0:
    BTCtest.loc[date,'Shares'] = 0
```

```
if BTCtest.loc[date,'Shares'] == 0:
    max(BTCtest.loc[date,'Shares'],-1)
```

Below is the result so far.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpVsI.png)
I don't want my position to go below 0.

Comment: What do you want to do with the shares when the position == 0? Do you want to delete these rows or do you want to give them another values?

Answer (score 0):

You should use .apply function instead of iterating over index. It will really simplify your code and it is the best practice.

Additionally, if you want to operate only with no zero rows do this:

```
BTCtest[BTCtest['Position'] == 0].apply(myfunction, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code, but I understand your title.

To convert negative values into positive, we can multiply it by '-1' if it is less than 0. So, write

```
numberr=int(input("Enter a number: "))
if numberr<0:
    numberr*=-1
print(numberr)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There are a bunch of other codes before that. But simply I'm trying to backtest my logic which is :
if MA10 > MA50 we buy one share,
if MA10 < MA50 we sell one share,
But I don't want my position to go below 0 as it doesn't make sense.